# My records are not updating (only 1st row of DataGridView)

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

```
private void applyUpdates(OleDbCommand myCommand, OleDbConnection Conn)
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
          String SQL = "Update UserList SET ActiveToday=@ActiveToday WHERE POID=@POID";
          myCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn);
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POID", row.Cells["POID"].Value.ToString());
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActiveToday", 1);

          Conn.Open();
          myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          Conn.Close();
    }
 }
```

The following is passed into the method above

```
string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Path\\database_be.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection();
Conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
OleDbCommand myCommand = Conn.CreateCommand();
```

There is no error or crashing. When I open the Access 2013 database, I see that only the 1st record updated. The others are untouched.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It is very odd to open and close the connection like that over and over. Why not keep it open over the lifetime of the foreach loop (or even better open it before you call the function and close it when you are done). Also you although you are closing your connection you are not disposeing of your objects. You really should be using `using` statements.

Comment: You also never use the command you pass in to the function, the first thing you do is throw it away and overwrite it with `myCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn);`

Comment: I dont think that is going to do much. I added it there to help me debug.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you post a solution in the answer section below. What do you mean by using?

Comment: I just confirmed that the first row keeps being updated. It doesn't make sense to me. I've getting the correct POID from the row.Cell (debug) However on updating, it keeps updating the first row

Comment: I think I remember a issue with access not respecting the names of your parameters and only looking at the order they where declared. If you swap the order of your two AddWithValue does it work?

Comment: Your answer made it work. Why dont you post it as a solution so I can give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue with parameters and Access. It does not look at the name of the parameters but instead at the order they are declared and used in the query. If you switch the order of your two `AddWithValue` calls it should fix it.

Here is also a updated version of your code using "best practices" using things like `using` statements to dispose of your commands and connection and renamed the variables and methods to follow [the naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx).

```
private void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Path\\database_be.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    using(var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        conn.Open();
        ApplyUpdates(conn);
    } //The using statement closes the connection for you. 
}


private void ApplyUpdates(OleDbConnection conn)
{
     var sql = "Update UserList SET ActiveToday=@ActiveToday WHERE POID=@POID";
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
          using(var myCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
          {
              myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //I think it is text by default and this is unnessary
              myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActiveToday", 1);
              myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POID", row.Cells["POID"].Value.ToString());
              myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
    }
}
```